# Which version to install: desktop or server?

Tags: installation

I have a RedHat Linux machine that I use to host subversion and run a number of CAD tools on.  RedHat is now so out-of-date that it refuses to update Firefox.  So I'd like to upgrade to Ubuntu.  I run Ubuntu on my laptop and remote access into the Redhat machine when out-of-towm.  I run the Redhat machine headless and always remote access it from a Windows machine (ugh) in my office.

Which is the correct version of Ubuntu to load to replace RedHat for my application.  I'm by no way a Linux expert but can usually find my way around with  a few hints!

Thanks

Comment: could you add some more info about your machine?

Answer (score 1):

For regular users 12.04 because is Long Term Support is the best choise.

If you know much stuff about it and you have time to find solutions on your own, you may choose 12.10

Comment: Ah yes but desktop or server.  I do need to support multi-user so I'm leaning to server??

Answer (score 0):

If you ran a headless server, I'd say choose the Ubuntu Server Edition, which excludes all the cruft like the xorg servers, a gui and the like. Just install openssh (`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`) and packages you need and you have a lean and mean server.

Since the Server Edition uses the same repository as the Desktop Edition, you can always upgrade it to a fully fledged desktop later on:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Oh and I'd suggest you go for the Long Term Support version, which currently is 12.04 (Precise Pangolin).